# unable to install lightgbm from jupyter notebook

Tags: machine-learning, lightgbm

In jupyter notebook, I did:

```
!pip3 install lightgbm
```

I got the following message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: lightgbm in /Users/tiger/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /Users/tiger/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from lightgbm) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/tiger/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from lightgbm) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /Users/tiger/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from lightgbm) (0.18.1)
```

It shows the package is installed. However, when I tried to import lightgbm:

```
import lightgbm as lgbm
```

I got the following message:

```
OSError: dlopen(/Users/tiger/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/tiger/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing `libomp` fixed this for me (MacOS):

```
brew install libomp
```

In Linux this should be:

```
sudo apt install libomp-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me on macOS.

```
$ brew install lightgbm
```

Answer (score 0):

If even after *brew instal libomp* the import is not working, also try to install lightgbm with brew

```
> brew install lightgbm
```

After running both brew commands, I was able to import the lightgbm in Jupyter notebook but not in Pycharm, so I recreated my venv in Pycharm and it worked.